# Socket Service has error when received a data in Android

Tags: android, android-networking

I am new to Android.

It runs well before receiving data from the Putty(PC)

but Error message printed when received a data

SocketServer$SocketServerThread.run(SocketServer.java:56)
"ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());"

If you have any comments about this problem, please let me know.

Thank you.

```
public class SocketServer extends Service {
    public SocketServer() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        SocketServerThread thread = new SocketServerThread();
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    class SocketServerThread extends Thread{
        public void run(){
            int port = 5001;

            try{
                ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
                Log.d("ServerThread", "Server Start");

                while (true){
                    try {
                        Socket socket = server.accept(); 

                        ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                        Object input = inputStream.readObject();
                        Log.d("ServerThread", "Input: " + input);

                        socket.close();
                    }
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e){
                        Log.d("ServerThread", "Server Error");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SocketServer.class);
        startService(intent);
}
```

Comment: `but Error message printed when received a data` That is your own message. Instead you should log e.getMessage() to know the cause. And post the stacktrace.

Comment: Do not combine those catch blocks. Separate them and put Log.d()'s in such a way that you know which was invoked.

Comment: @blackapps SocketServer$SocketServerThread.run(SocketServer.java:56) "ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());" / This is the error message. if different, please let me know.

Comment: I see no error message. You only quoted a code line.

Comment: @blackapps I am new to Android. I am so sorry if I do not understand what you mean.
Code is `ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());`
Error Message is **SocketServer$SocketServerThread.run(SocketServer.java:56) "ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());"**
If I understand wrong, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Post full stacktrace from logcat. Or from Putty. Its  unclear if putty is indeed the client.

Comment: `but Error message printed when received a data` It is already unclear who received data, or who tried to receive data and who printed that error message. Where? And you still do not log e.getMessage().

Comment: @blackapps Thank you for your help. I will close this question because I need more practice with android. I will re-design the app. Thank you so much again.